# Flutter: Changing boolean value to true onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I am new to Flutter and can't figure out why my boolean variable **clickedLike** isn't changing to true.

I declare this outside my Column, with the initial value false in a StatefulWidget class.

```
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      likeColor = Colors.blue;

                      if (clickedLike == false) {
                        numLikes++;
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('board')
                            .doc(docID)
                            .update({'likes': numLikes});
                        clickedLike = true;
                      } else {}
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: likeColor)
                  //color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
```

I have omitted the rest of the children widgets, as they are irrelevant. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to me that clickedLike is a boolean. In your code you’re comparing clickedLike == 0 and also clickedLike++. Is it not an int?

Comment: @ObjectJosh Have changed it to reflect my current code - clickedLike is a boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!clickedLike) {
                        numLikes++;
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('board')
                            .doc(docID)
                            .update({'likes': numLikes});
                        clickedLike = !clickedLike;
                      }
```

try this ?